# "Unable to locate Android Studio executable" error in vscode on MacOs Big Sur using Android Studio4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[image]

I am getting this error and can't figure out what could be the problem.

[image: right click]

[image: error]

Comment: Possible answer, same question https://stackoverflow.com/a/67407476/12295149