# Flutter with VS Code, Unable to locate Android Studio executable

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I re-installed Flutter and Android Studio.
I have already installed Java and SDK libraries and I can run the application from VS Code.
But when I tried to open Android module in Android Studio I am getting:

> Unable to locate Android Studio executable

[image: 1]

Comment: Same for me, it was just work before updating android studio to 2022, and the new version of dart extension in vs code

Answer (score 12):

if you are on mac the put this in :

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents"
```

Answer (score 2):

The Flutter extension locates Android Studio by calling `flutter config --machine`. It looks like Flutter isn't returning an Android Studio path there, so you could run:

```
flutter config android-studio-dir /path/to/android/studio
```

And then Flutter should remember it, and provide it to the VS Code extension when it looks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple go to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
folder and copy all Folder with files
then paste it on C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre folder
And Restart your PC.

Hope your Problem is gone.
Thank you

Comment: thanks, but i am using mac